# Run multiple inputs on Python from a list

Tags: python

I did a Python script that receives one input, a date (2020-01-01).

```
date_entry = datetime.strptime(input('Write the date YYYY-MM-DD:'), '%Y-%m-%d)
```

After it receives this input the script runs and does everything I want.

But now, I have a big list of files, `ListOfDates = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02', ...]`

Edit:

So my script runs one input at a time. I am fine with this. But I wanted not to have to give one input each time it finished the task. For example, I want the script to accept 2020-01-01 and when it finishes, then it will run 2020-01-02, and so on... without me having to type the input (the date), everytime it finishes the precious date.
Instead of typing one input at a time, and because I have a big list, how can I tell Python script to accept this list as input, and run one date at a time, without me typing every single date by hand?

Comment: Wrap all your current code with a `for date_entry in ListOfDates:`?

Comment: If list is available in code, then use for loop, if it is outside the program and you can copy paste then try to create one txt file and read it from there and do some string manipulation

Comment: So my script runs one input at a time. I am fine with this. But I wanted not to have to give one input each time it finished the task.
For example, I want the script to accept `2020-01-01` and when it finishes, then it will run `2020-01-02`, and so on... without me having to type the input (the date), everytime it finishes the precious date.

Comment: what is mean by "accept this list as input, and run one date at a time, without me typing every single date by hand" ?

Comment: So my input asks for a date, then runs and finishes. What I want is instead of having to run and type (the input ) for every single date. I would like the script to perform the task for every date in the list.

Comment: So loop the list of dates... I am not sure the exact problem is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
dates = input("Please provide space separated dates")
print(dates.split(" "))
```

and if you want to ignore redundant spaces:
print([d.strip() for d in dates.split(" ") if d != ""])

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate list:

```
ListOfDates = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02', ...]
for date in ListOfDates:
     print(date)
```

You can save a list of dates in a file and ask file path from user :

dates.txt:

```
'2020-01-01'
'2020-01-02'
'2020-01-03'
```

process.py:

```
file_path = input("enter file path :")
date_file = open(file_path,'r')
dates = date_file.read().split('\n')
for date in dates:
    print(date)
```